# npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@~8.2.4

Tags: angular, npm

When i am creating project in angular than get this error. Please suggest me how to resolve it.

> npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@~8.2.4

Comment: Can you add the complete command you are running, and the complete error message?

Comment: maybe it can help, but let me say, it was the first google result for the message you wrote. 

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14971#issuecomment-508235202

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue.
Just try to install it manually:

```
npm install -g @angular/compiler
```

then create new project.